# Swagger doesn't show specs when deployed (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, swagger, swagger-ui-express, swagger-node

Swagger is used with typescript with swagger-jsdocs and swagger-ui-express. It works perfectly fine on local and shows all the specs but when deployed it doesn't show any specs.

```
const options = {
  definition: {
    openapi: "3.1.0",
    info: {
      title: "SFMB Documentation",
      version: "0.1.0",
      description:
        "SFMB API Documentation",
    },
    components: {
      securitySchemes: {
        bearerAuth: {
          type: 'http',
          scheme: 'bearer',
          bearerFormat: 'JWT',
        }
      }
    },
    security: [{
      bearerAuth: []
    }],
    servers: [
      {
        url: "http://localhost:8080",
        description: "Local Server for version 1"
      },
    ],
  },
  apis: ["**/*.ts"]
};

const swaggerSpecs = swaggerJsdoc(options);
```

This is the swagger specs file

The actual swagger code are written in files

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /api/v1/location/locationParent:
 *   put:
 *     tags:
 *      - Location      
 *     summary: Update location Parent
 *     description: Update location Parent
```

```
"swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.8",
"swagger-ui-express": "^5.0.0",
```

These are the versions I am using.

This route is added for displaying the docs

```
app.use('/docs', swagger.serve, swagger.setup(swaggerSpecs));
```

Is it regarding the comments getting ignored when we transpile typescript code?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar error message. By setting "removeComments": false
in your tsconfig.json should do the trick. Also when deploying, I had to pass in to the "apis" field, .js files as it gets compiled to javascript files after deployment.